# TSQL WHERE clause for 25% Greater than another value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing some TSQL and need to find the following (written in pseudocode)...

```
WHERE OverallCPA 25% > TargetCPA
```

So essentially where the overallCPA value is 25% greater than the TargetCPA value

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: this is more a maths question... the basic algebraic operations in tsql are all available: - + * /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHERE OverallCPA > 1.25 * TargetCPA

Comment: HI, how could i do the same for < 3% ?

Comment: thank you so much for your help this all works a treat

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
WHERE (OverallCPA - TargetCPA)/TargetCPA > 0.25
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have two column CPA and TargetCPA (as KPI)

```
SELECT YourOtherColumn FROM YourTable
WHERE (((SELECT SUM(CPA) FROM YOUR COLUMN)-TargetCPA)/TargetCPA)>0.25
```